# How to set a minimum sdk version for a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

In my widget, I use collections (supported in Android >= 4.X).

Is there a way to set a widget so it will only appear in Android >= 4.X versions (without creating 2 apks)?

Answer (score 0):

Therefore, it works as in the normal Android App.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"    <!-- ANDROID GingerBrand --> 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />  <!-- ANDROID ICS-->
```

With Android 2.3 device the widget is not shown on the App tray.

Comment: The rest of my app supports android 2.3.
I do not want ~35% of the devices not to be able to download my app just because of my widget.

Comment: AFAIK, Android 3.0 introduces app widgets with collections. This is not supported on previous version. Update the answer.

Comment: I know it is not supported. I've seen apps that suggest different widgets on different operating systems. this is what I am asking; how (if) can this be done without uploading 2 apks